# proper way to consume local endpoint from another controller in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm working on a soon to be **legacy** *Rails App* and I need to consume a local endpoint.

What I need to do is something like this

controller A

1. response = restClient.call("some other local endpoint belong to controller B")
2. do some formatting on the response
3. return formatted response to client

What I'm doing now is using Faraday lib for rest call:

```
conn = Faraday.new(
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
      params: orig_params,
      headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
    )
response = conn.post('/api/v2/points/adjust')
format_response(response)
```

Is there a better way of doing so? what I was aiming for is like in a **controller test**
POST/GET like methods that 'knows' how to reach the local endpoint...

conceptually something like:

```
response = post('/api/v2/points/adjust')
format_response(response)
```

And yes, **its very bad design** but that is the constraint(as I mentioned it's a soon to be legacy app) I need to live with and the only questions what would be the best way to do it.

Comment: It's just fine, you don't need to make it better. If you realize issues you'll face in the future (network issues, slow response from your app because of parsing, e.t.c.), and If it's working fine for you now, then leave it as it is. You'll have to think about again when you'll face any issues with that design.

Comment: If you have to do this regularly (e.g. multiple endpoints, controllers, etc.) then I would build a basic Service Object that understands how to make a request and format a response and then just pass it the details it needs when you need to. If you are only doing this here then I would say leave it be, no need to over architect something you plan to throw away, better to work on things that aren't working.